# Javascript: How to add value to a list and make it instant update?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this problem with a function i'm trying to create.
I want the script to take the value of the input field, split on comma and put in an array who will be shown at once as a checkbox list.

Code looks like this

```
var names=new Array("Johnny","Brat","Anna");
function makelist(namelist){
    var rest = namelist.split(",");
    names.push.apply(names, rest);
}
```

And then I want the list to instant display in the form i created

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="task" value="buy beer" onClick="this.value=''"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="names"  onBlur="makelist(this.value)" value="add names seperate by comma" onClick="this.value=''"/><br/>
    <script>
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
            document.write("<input type='checkbox' name='navn" + i + "'/>" + names[i] + "<br/>");
        }
    </script>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="roll"/>
</form>
```

It seems to add the names to the array onblur, but I can't get it to show instant when the array is updated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You only add the `input` elements when the page loads.  Your `makelist` function would need to remove the existing `input` elements and add new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is, that the `for` loop is just executes once, when it is loaded first. When you want to update the DOM afterwards, you need some other approach.

Below, for example, a string is created containing all new elements. Then it is inserted into a wrapper `<div>` by using [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML).

HTML

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="task" value="buy beer" onClick="this.value=''"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="names"  onBlur="makelist(this.value)" value="add names seperate by comma" onClick="this.value=''"/><br/>
 <div id="checkboxes" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="roll"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
var names=new Array("Johnny","Brat","Anna");
function makelist(namelist){
  // insert to array
  var rest = namelist.split(",");
  names.push.apply(names, rest);

  // insert to dom
  var newEls = '';
  for( var i=0; i<rest.length; i++) {
   newEls += "<input type='checkbox' name='navn" + (names.length+i) + "'/>" + rest[i] + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById( 'checkboxes' ).insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', newEls );
}
```

Comment: This works great! One problem though, it's not showing the list which is already there. The Johnny, Brat, Anna names. How to do that? And then adding onto that

Comment: @user2979822 Run the code after "insert to dom" on documentReady using `names` instead of `rest`. Same principle, just another array.